# Why does the twitter widget not re-render reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

I am using the twitter embedded timeline on my application to show the twitter feed of a companies twitter account.

When I get a result from an API, the state changes to the correct values, but the twitter widget does not appear to change

TwitterCard.js

```
import React from "react";

export class TwitterCard extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <a className="twitter-timeline" href={this.props.href} data-height="100%">Tweets by {this.props.ticker}</a>
        )
    }
}
```

I have attached screenshots of the react plugin output for proof of state change.

[image: Correctly rendered page]

[image: Incorrectly rendered page]

The parent class is rather large, so I have posted the render method:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar/>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <NavBarSide clickHandler={(url) => this.handleNavClick(url)}/>
                        <Dashboard
                            errorChart={this.state.errorChart}
                            twitter={this.state.twitter}
                            status={this.state.status}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The parent passes these values to the Dashboard:

```
import React from "react";

import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Chart } from "./Chart";
import { TwitterCard } from "./TwitterCard";


export class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-2 px-3">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-8">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <div className="card border-0">
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <Chart chart={this.props.errorChart}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-4">
                        <TwitterCard href={this.props.twitter} ticker={this.props.ticker}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the parent?

Comment: The parent is quite a large class which does a lot. Would the render method be useful?

Comment: Potentially that could be good enough to determine the issue

Comment: I don't see where `<TwitterCard />` is rendered still

Comment: Ahhh, the `<TwitterCard/>` is rendered within the dashboard, so I will post that.

Comment: Show the Dashboard component.

Answer (score 1):

You can force an update to the twitter component when the ticket changes by keying it with the ticker where you render it in your dashboard component:

```
<TwitterCard
  key={this.props.ticker}
  href={this.props.twitter}
  ticker={this.props.ticker}
/>
```

Comment: Upon adding this, I get the error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

Comment: Can you try adding a <div> surrounding the <a> in your TwitterCard component? I believe another library is manipulating the node we've keyed causing that issue

Comment: Adding a div stopped the error, but now the widget is not re-rendering. The handle has changed which is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Have you looked into the issue tracker of the library you're using to manipulate the node and show the tweets?

Comment: I will take a look :) Cheers for all the help.